# Calling Wordpress PHP function from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to pass a checkbox value when it is checked from an AJAX form. Now I get the value to my AJAX function but I have no success in calling a PHP function then/passing the value to PHP.

Here is the AJAX function (applicantid.js), I get the alert message with correct value here:

```
function sendAjaxRequest(value){
jQuery.ajax({
 url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
 data: ({action : 'get_my_option', value:value}),
      success: function() {
       alert(value);
      }

 });
}
```

Here is the code with the PHP function I've added to functions.php:

```
function your_function_name() 
{

 wp_enqueue_script( 'myfunction', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/applicantid.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0',true);
 wp_localize_script( 'myfunction', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


}

add_action('template_redirect', 'your_function_name');

function get_my_option()
{

$value = $_POST['value'];
$applicantid = get_field('applicant id', $value);
$wp_session[$value] = $applicantid;
//print($value);

}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
```

I'm really lost here and not sure what is wrong. I appreciate your support, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close, three problems I can spot

1. Your `get_my_option()` function is not sending back anything. You should do.

   ```
   function get_my_option()
   {
       //get applicant id (looks like this is what you want to get back?)

       //send json headers
       header( "Content-Type: application/json" );

       //print out you response as json
       echo json_encode( $applicantid );

       //must have an exit in the ajax action callback!
       exit();

   }
   ```
2. Your jquery ajax request isn't looking for the response, you success function should look like

   ```
   success: function( response ){
       console.log( response );
   })
   ```
3. Your jquery ajax request doesn't have a type set, and so will be sent as a GET but your callback looks for a POST variable. Use `type: 'POST'` as an option for the ajax call.

---

Using something like the network tab on chrome developer tools you can look at what's going. You should see a request to admin-ajax.php and you can look at the request actually getting sent and the response.

Comment: Hey, thank for your support; adding "type: 'POST'" to AJAX allowed sending the value to the PHP function, and the "console.log" shows that the value is getting passed back to AJAX. Now my biggest problem is adding the value to session ($wp_session[$value] = $applicantid; - doesn't work). I know that's a different topic, but maybe have some suggestions for that? Thank you!